# Meteor import async function to be used in a method call

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor app gives the error  `TypeError: vinXXX is not a function` when trying to call an exported async function saved in a const variable "vinXXX" from within a method call in a sibiling folder which has been imported in the methods follder. Any idea why and how to fix it?
Thanks

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import { vinXXX } from './vinXXX.js'
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
module.exports = vinXXX;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the exports to be `vinXXX` itself, not an object containing it. So your import needs to be for the default:

```
import vinXXX from './vinXXX.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically you've got ES module import syntax mixed with commonJS export syntax. These two can be mixed due to the way that Meteor transpiles the code, but you have to understand how each works so that you can store and retrieve the data so the work together.

To get it working with the mixed syntaxes, either your import needs to be changed to ES module default import syntax, or you need to change your export to have a named property on the exported object.

Changing the export to be an object that has a property of your named import

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import vinXXX from './vinXXX.js'
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});

//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
module.exports = { vinXXX };
```

Changing the import to a default ES Module import

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import { vinXXX } from './vinXXX.js'
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
module.exports = vinXXX;
```

You can of course use to one or the other syntax without mixing them.

CommonJS default export

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

const vinXXX = require('./vinXXX.js')
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
module.exports = vinXXX;
```

CommonJs named export

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

const { vinXXX } = require('./vinXXX.js')
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
module.exports = { vinXXX };
```

ES Module default syntax

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import vinXXX from './vinXXX.js'
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

export default async (plate, state) => {...}
```

ES Module Named export

```js
//imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import { vinXXX } from './vinXXX.js'
Meteor.methods({
    'extractData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        vinXXX(plate, 'UUU');  // CAR HISTORY
    }
});



//imports/api/vehicles/vinXXX.js

export const vinXXX = async (plate, state) => {...}
```